# Linker cant find .cpp implementation of a header file (MSVC)

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, msvcrt

I'm trying to build a project with the MSVC compiler (cl.exe),
the command is

`start /b /wait "" "cl.exe"  %build_options% %compile_flags% ..\src\win32_main.cpp  /link /LIBPATH:..\src\ %link_flags% /out:%application_name%`

I have set LIBPATH to where the cpp implementations to my headers are but all I get is an unresolved external.
Note, I have no problem running my project without cpp files (meaning everything being inside a header, included in my main and worked through there, the problem is that the linker can't find the implementation of .h files).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
[my files are structured like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoOlg.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Not exactly, I kinda know the compilation steps, my main problem is that I don't know how I can set the LIBPATH in the MSVC Compiler. The unresolved external is probably there because the path is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct problem that you have is that you need to link `*.obj` files, or possibly `*.lib` files built from those `.obj` files, but definitely not `.cpp` files.

I suggest that you stick with Visual Studio. The root cause of your problem is that you're reinventing the wheel. The MSVC compiler is designed to be called by a build environment.